# Java Vert.x and SockJS through Eventbus

Tags: java, vert.x, sockjs

I would like to use Vert.x 3.3.2 and socketJS with the eventbus proxy to forget about URL's once and for all but just to talk in messages without creating REST interfaces -best thing in years on the Java platform!. However, my hello world is not working.

My test is as follows: on every connected and disconnected event clientside and serverside, it is printed at the console. And, when a client is connected, the client sends a message on which the server respons, and the server sends a notification to everyone too. What happens is that only the first client sends its message and gets proper response from the server.

Java:

```
public class App extends AbstractVerticle {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getName());
}

@Override
public void start() throws IOException {
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    BridgeOptions options = new BridgeOptions();
    PermittedOptions address = new PermittedOptions().setAddress("some-address");
    options.addInboundPermitted(address);
    options.addOutboundPermitted(address);
    SockJSHandler sockJSHandler = SockJSHandler.create(vertx).bridge(options, be -> {
        if (be.type() == BridgeEventType.REGISTER) {
            System.out.println("sockJs: connected");
            vertx.eventBus().publish("some-address", "hey all, we have a new subscriber ");
        }
        be.complete(true);
    });
    router.route("/sockjs/*").handler(sockJSHandler);
    router.route("/web/*").handler(StaticHandler.create("doc/clientSocketJS"));
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8020, listenHandler -> {
        if (listenHandler.failed()) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Startup error", listenHandler.cause());
            System.exit(0); // stop on startup error
        }
    });
    vertx.eventBus().consumer("some-address", message -> {
        System.out.println("sockJs: received: " + message.body());
        message.reply("I received so I reply");
    });

    }

}
```

In folder doc/clientSocketJS there is a index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sockjs/0.3.4/sockjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vertx-eventbus.js"></script>
<script>
    var eb = new EventBus('http://localhost:8020/sockjs');
    eb.onopen = function() {
        console.log('connected');
        eb.registerHandler('some-address', function(error, message) {
            console.log('received: ' + JSON.stringify(message));
        });
        eb.send('some-address', {
            name : 'from ' + navigator.product
        }, null, function(a, message) {
            if (message == null) {
                console.log("ERROR: response null");
            } else {
            console.log('response: ', message.body);
            }
        });
    }
    eb.onclose = function() {
        console.log("disconnected");
        eb = null;
    };
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Responses are as follows:

First browser client is loaded:
SERVER:

```
sockJs: connected
sockJs: received: hey all, we have a new subscriber 
sockJs: received: {"name":"from Gecko"}
```

CLIENT 1:

```
connected
response: I received so I reply
```

This is as expected. Then I load a second client (same or other browser):

SERVER

```
sockJs: connected
sockJs: received: hey all, we have a new subscriber 
(expecting a 'name' just like first time, but it doesn't appear)
```

CLIENT 2:

```
connected
(after a while) ERROR: response null  @ index.html::18
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You Java code seems totally fine. But JavaScript code looks like it was taken from an old example.
First parameter of registerHandler callback is the message itself, not error.
I also used hosted VertxEventBus, instead of the provided, just in case.

This should work:

```js
var eb = new vertx.EventBus('http://localhost:8020/sockjs');
        eb.onopen = function() {
            console.log('connected');
            eb.registerHandler('some-address', function(message) {
                console.log('received: ' + JSON.stringify(message));
            });
            eb.send('some-address', {
                name : 'from ' + navigator.product
            }, null, function(a, message) {
                if (message == null) {
                    console.log("ERROR: response null");
                } else {
                    console.log('response: ', message.body);
                }
            });
        };
        eb.onclose = function() {
            console.log("disconnected");
            eb = null;
        };
```

```html
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sockjs/0.3.4/sockjs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vertx/2.0.0/vertxbus.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: tnx! However it looks like you use using old code. Check the 'registerHandler' call in the example at 
the docs [link](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_sockjs_event_bus_bridge) and check the Changelog from 3.0.x to 3.1 at [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vertx3-eventbus-client). However, the js might be old indeed, I'll try to get it from a CDN.

Comment: The github [link](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-bus-bower) looks like the latest source, not the npmjs